# Assigning values of an object to a column in Loop through R

Tags: r

This is snippet of my R code. I am trying to assign the value of `resultsdata[i]` to column `Error`
but the values are not assigning. Results are coming in console but somehow i am not able to assign it the required column

```
resultsData=foreach(i=1:length(xyzArr)) %dopar% {    
  xyzRed[xyzsRed$loopN==xyzArr[i],]$SETPOINT-xyzRed[xyzRed$loopN==xyzArr[i],]$TEMP
}
foreach(i=1:length(xyzArr)) %dopar%{
  xyzRed[xyzRed$loopN==dataPointsArr[i],]$Error=resultsData[[i]]
}

Results in console:
[[1]]
 [1] 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 1.186 2.266 2.266 2.266 2.266 2.266
[19] 2.266 2.266 2.266 2.266 1.384 2.392 2.392
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the combine feature.  The general approach is to calculate a column, then output the entire row.  Lastly, the row binding logic puts it all together.

```
xyzArr$var_name_here <- numeric(nrow(xyzArr))
resultsData <- foreach(i=1:length(xyzArr), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {    
xyzArr[i,]$var_name_here <- xyzRed[xyzsRed$loopN==xyzArr[i],]$SETPOINT-xyzRed[xyzRed$loopN==xyzArr[i],]$TEMP
xyzArr[i,]
}
```